# Help identifying cause of yellowing fruit tree leaves?

Tags: watering

thank you for any insight any of you might provide.

I have four fruit trees in my yard, a Red Haven peach planted in Fall '17, a Liberty Apple and a Ginger Gold apple planted in Spring '18, and a Mericrest Nectarine just planted in Spring '19.  I live in zone 6a and have moderately sandy soil.

Starting a few weeks ago I noticed that the peach tree had yellowing leaves, especially the smaller inner leaves.  Given that we have had a very wet spring, about 18 inches this spring and 4 in May, ([rainfall this spring](https://www.weather.gov/ind/climategraphhuf2019)) I have barely been watering the trees.  None of my other plants (azaleas, hydrangeas, etc) seem lacking for water.

Can anyone tell me why my leaves are yellowing?  Too much water? Too little water? Nutrient deficiency?  Some kind of infection?

Thanks again for any input.

Here are some pictures of what I'm talking about:

**Red Haven Peach:**

You can see the yellowing leaves as well as somethine eating the leaves I think on the peach tree.

[image: Peach yellowing leaves]
[image: More peach yellowing]

**Mericrest Nectarine**

The nectarine tree seems to be doing well, but is now starting to yellow as well.
[image: Nectarine Leaves]

**Apple trees**

Again, starting to yellow on the inner leaves.
[image: Ginger Gold]
[image: Liberty]

Answer (score 1):

I think those leaves are the first to break from the bud and they just die... the plant looks healthy... They every one look like the most basal, most shaded leaf... I don't think you have a problem at all.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!